# Azure Service Bus Consumer becomes slow over time

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have different topics with subscriptions, and each subscription has a consumer. The problem is as time passes , The number of messages gets lower. I have used maxconcurrentcalls. But it also seems to be working in start only. I am using azure/service-bus npm package. and [Azure bus code sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/v7/typescript/src/receiveMessagesStreaming.ts) using the code for consuming message. although made some changes to it for concrrent calls and autocomplete messages.

I had a single connection for all consumers earlier, I tried making an individual connection for each consumer. but it didn't help.

Code:

```
let receiver: any
let sbClient: ServiceBusClient
try {
    sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
    logger.info("Azure connection is establish successfully for topic:", topic)
}
catch (Err) {
    logger.error("Error in subscribing events from azure service bus", Err)
    return
}
try {
    receiver = sbClient?.createReceiver(topic, subscriptionName);
    logger.debug(`Receiver for ${topic} Connected Successfully.`)
}
catch (err) {
    sbClient?.close()
    logger.error(`Error in creating receiver for ${topic}`, err)
    return null
}

try {
    const subscription = receiver.subscribe({
        processMessage: async (brokeredMessage: ServiceBusReceivedMessage) => {
            var input = brokeredMessage.body
            let result = await processData(input)
            if (result) {
                await receiver.completeMessage(brokeredMessage)
            } else {
                await receiver.abandonMessage(brokeredMessage)
            }
        },


        processError: async (args: any) => {
            logger.error(`Error from source ${args.errorSource} occurred: `, args.error);

            // the `subscribe() call will not stop trying to receive messages without explicit intervention from you.
            if (isServiceBusError(args.error)) {
                switch (args.error.code) {
                    case "MessagingEntityDisabled":
                    case "MessagingEntityNotFound":
                    case "UnauthorizedAccess":
                        // It's possible you have a temporary infrastructure change (for instance, the entity being
                        // temporarily disabled). The handler will continue to retry if `close()` is not called on the subscription - it is completely up to you
                        // what is considered fatal for your program.
                        logger.error(
                            `An unrecoverable error occurred. Stopping processing. ${args.error.code}`,
                            args.error
                        );
                        await subscription.close();
                        break;
                    case "MessageLockLost":
                        logger.error(`Message lock lost for message`, args.error);
                        break;
                    case "ServiceBusy":
                        // choosing an arbitrary amount of time to wait.
                        await delay(1000);
                        break;
                    default:
                        logger.error("Error in processing message", args)
                }
            }
        },
    }, { autoCompleteMessages: false, maxConcurrentCalls: 100 });

    return receiver
}
catch (err) {
    await receiver?.close();
    logger.error("Error in subscribing messages", err)
    return null
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please share(or) update your code,

Comment: I have updated the code I am using to create receivers .

Comment: some measure autoCompleteMessages to false, adjusting the prefetchCount property and lockDuration

Comment: ```try {
    receiver = sbClient.createReceiver(topic, subscriptionName, {
      receiveMode: "peekLock",
      maxConcurrentCalls: 100,
      autoCompleteMessages: false,
    });```

Comment: with above sample condition [input](https://i.imgur.com/nHYWLU5.png)          [Output](https://i.imgur.com/ATM7Dep.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below points to speed up the process :

- `autoCompleteMessages` should be set to false. As a result, depending on the processing outcome, to avoid building up unfinished messages, which can slow down the consumer, and check that you are swiftly completing messages after processing.
- Use receiver's prefetchCount attribute. The prefetch count establishes the maximum number of messages the receiver can request in a single request.
- lockDuration setting sets  How long a message is locked for processing by a consumer is determined by the lock duration.

```js
receiveMode:  "peekLock",
maxConcurrentCalls:  30,
autoCompleteMessages:  false,
```

**CODE:**

```
const  {  ServiceBusClient  } = require("@azure/service-bus");
async  function  startConsumer(connectionString,  topic,  subscriptionName)  {
let  receiver;
let  sbClient;
try  {
sbClient = new  ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
console.log("Azure connection established successfully for topic:",  topic);
}  catch (err) {
console.error("Error in connecting to Azure Service Bus:",  err);
return;
}
try  {
receiver = sbClient.createReceiver(topic,  subscriptionName,  {
receiveMode:  "peekLock",
maxConcurrentCalls:  30,
autoCompleteMessages:  false,
});
console.log(`Receiver for ${topic} connected successfully.`);
}  catch (err) {
sbClient.close();
console.error(`Error in creating receiver for ${topic}:`,  err);
return  null;
}
const  processMessage = async  (brokeredMessage)  =>  {
const  input = brokeredMessage.body.toString();
const  result = await  processData(input);
if (result) {
await  receiver.completeMessage(brokeredMessage);
}  else  {
await  receiver.abandonMessage(brokeredMessage);
}
};
const  processError = async  (args)  =>  {

console.error(`Error from source ${args.errorSource} occurred:`,  args.error);

if (args.error.code === "MessagingEntityDisabled" ||
args.error.code === "MessagingEntityNotFound" ||
args.error.code === "UnauthorizedAccess") {

console.error("An unrecoverable error occurred. Stopping processing.",  args.error);

await  receiver.close();

}  else  if (args.error.code === "MessageLockLost") {

console.error("Message lock lost for message",  args.error);

}  else  if (args.error.code === "ServiceBusy") {

await  customDelay(1000); 

}  else  {

console.error("Error in processing message",  args);

}

};

const  subscription = receiver.subscribe({

processMessage,

processError,

});
return  receiver;

}
async  function  processData(input)  {
console.log("Processing message:",  input);
return  true;

}
function  customDelay(ms)  {
return  new  Promise((resolve)  =>  setTimeout(resolve,  ms));

}
const  connectionString = "Endpoint=sb:";
const  topic = "sam";
const  subscriptionName = "sampath";
startConsumer(connectionString,  topic,  subscriptionName)
.then((receiver)  =>  {
if (receiver) {
console.log("Consumer started successfully.");
}  else  {
console.log("Failed to start the consumer.");
}
})
.catch((err)  =>  {
console.error("An error occurred while starting the consumer:",  err);
});
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I already have autoCompleteMessages as false and using maxConcurrentCalls and using peekLock. But I can't use prefetch as the Azure document says it is not supported in Javascript SDK. Do you happen to know any alternative?

Comment: Even I too do not find any insights on this, verified all the MSDocs and SO links. And gave you all the insights based on the my findings.